# Same Issue in Two Tests: Something Wrong With Events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot, testunit

I believe something is wrong with the creation of events in my testing environment.

When I navigate in the browser everything is fine.

The two errors I get are:

```
 1) Error:
test_should_post_save_period(PeriodRegistrationsControllerTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `event' for nil:NilClass

 2) Error:
test_should_get_index(PeriodsControllerTest):
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Error 1 test:

```
  def setup
    @period_registration= FactoryGirl.create(:period_registration)
  end
  test "should post save_period" do
    sign_in(FactoryGirl.create(:user))
     assert_difference('PeriodRegistration.count') do
      post :save_period, period_registration: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:period_registration)
    end
    assert_not_nil assigns(:period_registration)

    # assert_response :success
  end
```

Error 2 test:

```
 test "should get index" do
        sign_in(FactoryGirl.create(:user, admin: true))
        get :index
        assert_not_nil assigns(:periods)
        assert_response :success
      end
```

Error number one corresponds with this action in the controller:

```
 def save_period
    @period_registration = PeriodRegistration.new(params[:registration])
    @period_registration.save
    flash[:success] = "Successfully Registered for Session."
    redirect_to event_url(@period_registration.period.event) #problem line
  end
```

The second error corresponds with this line in my view:

`<h6><%= period.event.name %> in <%= period.event.city %>, <%= period.event.state%></h6>`

Here is my event factory:

```
  factory :event do
    name 'First Event'
    street '123 street'
    city 'Chicago'
    state 'Iowa'
    date Date.today
  end

 factory :period do
    name 'First Period'
    description 'This is a description'
    start_time Time.now + 10.days
    end_time Time.now + 10.days + 2.hours
    event
    product
  end

factory :period_registration do
    user
    period
  end
```

And my event model looks like this:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: events
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  date       :date
#  street     :string(255)
#  city       :string(255)
#  state      :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime        not null
#  updated_at :datetime        not null
#

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city, :date, :name, :state, :street
  has_many :periods

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :street, presence: true
  validates :city, presence: true
  validates :state, presence: true
end
```

and here is my period model:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: periods
#
#  id          :integer         not null, primary key
#  name        :string(255)
#  event_id    :integer
#  created_at  :datetime        not null
#  updated_at  :datetime        not null
#  start_time  :time
#  end_time    :time
#  description :text
#  product_id  :integer
#

    class Period < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :event_id, :name, :time, :start_time, :end_time, :description, :product_id
      belongs_to :event
      belongs_to :product
      has_many :period_registrations

      validates_time :end_time
      validates_time :start_time
      validates_presence_of :name
      validates_presence_of :start_time
      validates_presence_of :end_time
      validates_presence_of :description
    end
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: Show us your period model and factory and the tests that you are running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because `FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:period_registration)` returns {} (empty hash). You can check it in rails console. And also you have typo in code: in test you send `period_registration: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:period_registration)`, but in controller you expects `params[:registration]`. This leads to the empty PeriodRegistration model is created in db. This model does not contain event_id and when you request event from model, it returns nil.

Why you do not use mock for these kind of tests?

Comment: I am relatively new to testing and still trying to figure out how it all goes together. Would mocks be a better solution?

Comment: I think for these kind of tests mock is better then real model. Btw I prefer rspec over test::unit.

Comment: Have you used minitest? I think I'm going to try to use that on my next project.

Comment: @NoahClark Yes. I used minitest. I think it is good and I plan used it in my next project.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are missing your Factory for the User model

Comment: I have that, I just didn't post it.